# PDF intermittently shows a grey box in Safari

Tags: pdf, safari, race-condition

There is an issue with Safari (on desktop) where PDF previews intermittently fail. I've observed this with files around 2MB, but not those under 1MB.

It seemed like a race condition, potentially in the code that generates the signed link however I've since narrowed it down to a Safari bug.

The symptoms are:

- Intermittently failing Byte Range requests
- Duplicate Byte Range requests (may or may not be an issue)
- The preview shows empty, which essentially means a large grey box with the usual actions within the pdf viewer for downloading etc.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to use `iframe` instead of `embed`.

This does not appear to be an easy bug to search the solution for, and I've not a clue why it is a problem in the first place, however there is a documented report over on https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject/issues/243 which is where I found the solution.

I've also written a short blog post about it: https://shanehudson.net/articles/2022/pdf-breaking-safari/

Comment: This may not be an appropriate solution for Safari on iOS, as that seems to have different pdf/iframe-related issues. Thankfully in this case, that was already handled.